# List is not printing out the way I want it to. I need help to figure out how to print it correctly

Tags: python, list, function, file

I'm supposed to take individual articles, sort them out per month (there are 11 months for this), and print the list. I have appended each word to the list wordsList; however it is not printing out the way I need it to, and I'm unsure on how to get it to do what I want. Here's a part of the code. (I put two #'s, one below and one above what seems to be part of the problem.

```
def process_file(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    nextL = file.readline()
    wordsList = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

    while nextL != '':
        if nextL[0:3] == 'URL':
            url = nextL
            get_week(url)

            nextL = file.readline()

        else:
            for i in nextL:
                while nextL[0:3] != 'URL':
                    aux = ''
                    nextL = nextL.split()
                    for i in nextL:
                        a = i.strip('—;“.”:!,?')
                        aux += a
                        wordsList[get_week(url)].append(aux.lower())

                        #
                        weekly_tokens = print(wordsList)
                        #

                        aux = ''
                        
                    nextL = file.readline()
    file.close()

    return weekly_tokens


def main():
    process_file(get_filename())
    #process_file(filename) ?
    #print(weekly_tokens) ?
main()
```

Below is the output. Instead of what is happening below, I wanted to print out only the last list: [['behsud', 'afghanistan', '', 'the', 'first'], [], ['it’s', 'the', 'rare', 'wine'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]. How can I get it to print out only that one? (It shouldn't output the first 8 lines)

```
Enter a file name: articles.txt
[['behsud'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['behsud', 'afghanistan'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['behsud', 'afghanistan', ''], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['behsud', 'afghanistan', '', 'the'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['behsud', 'afghanistan', '', 'the', 'first'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['behsud', 'afghanistan', '', 'the', 'first'], [], ['it’s'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['behsud', 'afghanistan', '', 'the', 'first'], [], ['it’s', 'the'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['behsud', 'afghanistan', '', 'the', 'first'], [], ['it’s', 'the', 'rare'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['behsud', 'afghanistan', '', 'the', 'first'], [], ['it’s', 'the', 'rare', 'wine'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Everything else is working fine, I just only want to show the finished list, and not the previous versions of it. (Also, I am a beginner, so sorry if my code is horrific). If you could explain to me what I did wrong and how the problem can be fixed, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the print function does not return anything, it just prints its arguments straight to the console.
Thus, the reason you are seeing eight lines printed is because the print statement is within the for loop. Take it some layers up and the solution is as follows:

```
def process_file(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    nextL = file.readline()
    wordsList = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

    while nextL != '':
        if nextL[0:3] == 'URL':
            url = nextL
            get_week(url)

            nextL = file.readline()

        else:
            for i in nextL:
                while nextL[0:3] != 'URL':
                    nextL = nextL.split()
                    for i in nextL:
                        aux = ''
                        a = i.strip('—;“.”:!,?')
                        aux += a
                        wordsList[get_week(url)].append(aux.lower())
                        
                    nextL = file.readline()
    file.close()

    print(wordsList)
```

Let me know if it fixed your issue. I wasn't able to run a test.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not print anything out when I do that. My goal is to return the variable weekly_tokens, which should print the list wordsList. Thanks for the help, though :)

Comment: In your example what was printed was `words_list`, so it is curious why nothing shows up when running my solution. In your example `weekly_tokens` was `None` since it was assigned by the `print` function. So if you want  `words_list` to be returned, simply add `return word_list` at the end of `process_file`, then call `print` on the output of its call.